# Changing text in several table cells with external javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getelementsbytagname

I have a calender type deal that I am trying to create and I am hung up on selecting and changing several `<td>` elements in one go. I plan on using a for loop to accomplish this by traversing each node and modifying its text each iteration, but I am confused on how to actually access the text. If I have, in my external:

```
var daysInWeek = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

And in HTML:

```
<tr><td id="w1_mo">w1d1</td>
                        <td id="w1_tu">w1d2</td>
                        <td id="w1_we">w1d3</td>
                        <td id="w1_th">w1d4</td>
                        <td id="w1_fr">w1d5</td>
                        <td id="w1_sa">w1d6</td>
                        <td id="w1_su">w1d7</td></tr>
```

Five of them

How do I go about accessing the node next to the previous and changing its text?
It would appear that the dot operator does not give me the same options as `.getElementById()` does. I understand there is also `.item(index: int)` as well but it would appear I get the same options as elements by tag name. 
Suggestions for a noob Javascripter?

Comment: Can you add your HTML code as well?  It would help to be able to see how your table is constructed.

Comment: What do you mean by *"accessing the node next to the previous and changing its text"*?? The next/previous `td`? The text *in* the `td`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate "the dot operator does not give me the same options as .getElementById() does." What dot operator? What options? Please show the code you have.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes to both. The next td and te text within it

Comment: @ZFN7: Okay, both are covered in my answer. Not sure why you want to access the *next* element, though, as it'll almost certainly be a `td` and you already have them in the list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` gives you a `NodeList` with matching elements in it. You access the elements using either A) brackets notation: `[n]` where `n` is `0 <= n < list.length`, or B) Using `.item(n)` (same range for `n`).

So for instance, this accesses the first `td` in the document:

```
var daysInWeek = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var firstTdInDocument = daysInWeek[0];
```

That's an `HTMLElement` object. To access its contents, you use:

- ...its `childNodes` property to access **all** of its direct child nodes. `childNodes` is a `NodeList` containing `Text` and `Element` nodes (and possibly `Comment`nodes)
- ...its `children` property if you want a subset of `childNodes` that only includes `Element` instances
- ...its `textContent` (standard) or `innerText` (IE-specific) property to access its contents as straight text (markup is stripped out)
- ...its `innerHTML` property to access its contents as HTML
- ...its `nextSibling` or `nextElementSibling` properties if you want to access the `Node` (`nextSibling`) or `Element` (`nextElementSibling`) that follows it in the tree (in the case of `td` elements, that's usually another `td` element or `null`)
- ...its `previousSibling` or `previousElementSibling` to go the other way

So for instance, to set the HTML of the first `td` in the document:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML = "I'm the first <code>td</code> element";
```

Note that you're not limited to crude things like `getElementsByTagName` anymore; you can use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` to get the first matching element or a list of matching elements, respectively, for any arbitrary CSS expression. This is supported on `document` and also on `Element` instances on all modern browsers, and also IE8+.

So for instance, another way to update the text of the first `td` in the document is:

```
document.querySelector("td").innerHTML = "I'm the first <code>td</code> element";
```

Or

```
document.querySelectorAll("td")[0].innerHTML = "I'm the first <code>td</code> element";
```

More in the [DOM specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fi/docs/DOM).

Comment: This all makes perfect sense. Thank you, I didn't understand that the variable I declared was technically an array. And I just started learning, so I was unaware of query selector. Your post helped in my understanding, so thank you

Comment: @ZFN7: Happy to help! Technically, it isn't an array, it's a `NodeList` (specifically, in the case of `getElementsByTagName`, a **live** `NodeList` -- if you added more `td` elements to the document later, they'd magically appear in the list; `querySelectorAll` returns a *disconnected* `NodeList` instead). But you can access `NodeList` elements via `[]` notation and it has a `length` property. :-) It just doesn't have other array features, like `splice` or `map`...

Comment: I see, that is all very good to know! I appreciat your time :)